# ARM benchmarking tool (busybox)

Tags: c++, arm, benchmarking, busybox

I'm looking for a benchmarking suite compatible with ARM processors (possibly running Busybox and with not many dependencies).
Is there anything out there for this purpose?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to benchmark (CPU performance, memory, network, etc)? On what platform (Linux, Windows, Android, proprietary OS, etc)?

Comment: I'm looking to benchmark as much as I can :). Definitely CPU, memory and file operations. If possible, networking as well, on ARM Linux (Busybox)